# Add custom field information to source meta data

Tags: custom-field, single, post-meta, wp-blog-header.php

I try to add information from a custom field into the metadata in the source code. While searching for the solutions I found some. As I am not really an expert I ask you guys. 
I want to add information for a Digital Object Identifier (DOI) from a custom field to the source code so that the Search Engine of Altmetrics can find it. Necessary meta tags are:

- Identifier (e.g. citation_doi)
- Title (e.g. citation_title)
- Author (e.g. citation_author)
- ISSN - if applicable (e.g. citation_issn)

Finally, it should look like this in the Page Source:

```
<meta name="citation_title" content="A qualitative study" />
<meta name="citation_journal_title" content="Accountability in Research" />
<meta name="citation_author" content="David Shaw" />
<meta name="citation_doi" scheme="doi" content="10.1080/08989621.2017.1413940" />
<meta name="citation_source" content="https://doi.org/10.1080/08989621.2017.1413940" />
```

Some more comments: the DOI is unique for every blogpost. If you want to see the page look here: https://elephantinthelab.org/
I could really need help, especially in which .php-File I should put the information. I am also happy if you know a plugin which does the job. All SEO plugins I tried are not flexible enough.
Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to add some metaboxes to your posts. This has been answered a lot, and there are many posts on the internet about is, such as [this full guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-meta-boxes-post-types-wordpress/).

After adding metaboxes, you can hook into the `wp_head` action hook and output your metadata. Here's a simple piece of code that goes into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'add_my_metadata' );
function add_my_metadata() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        ?><meta name="citation_title" content="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key_here', true ); ?>" /><?php
    }
}
```

Make sure that your theme has the `wp_head()` function inside its `header.php` file, so the action hook can actually print the above code.

Comment: I managed to build a meta box with "Meta Box"-Plugin where I can put something in the box. Also your function works as I see it in the source code. Unfortunately, the content is empty. I just replaced your 'meta_key_here' with what I think is the meta key. Do I need to change something else?
And by the way: thank your so much for helping me! That's not my "home" coding language :)

Comment: I managed now to have my own meta box and everything works perfectly fine except that the "content" says "Array" although there is a value in there. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have to set the last parameter of `get_post_meta` to true, so it returns a single value. Otherwise, it will return an array of metas.